# to retrieve the names of players in django

Tags: django

class is player to retrieve the names of all the players in house name
models:

```
class player(models.Model):

    """
    Model representing a book genre (e.g. Science Fiction, Non Fiction).
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Enter a players name")
    Id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100, help_text="Enter a players Id")



    Num_matches = models.IntegerField()
    Num_baskets = models.IntegerField()
    house_name = models.ForeignKey('House_name',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)


    def __str__(self):  
        """
        String for representing the Model object (in Admin site etc.)
        """
        return self.Id
```

views

```
def shivalik(request):


   set1 = player.objects.filter(house_name__hou_name='shivalik')

   return render(request,'shivalik.html',
              context={'set1':set1 }
                       )
```

html file

```
{% block content %}


     <h2>{{set1}}</h2>

{% end block %}
```

In shivalik.html it is not printing the names of player it is printing the query.
I tried to keep set1.name in views but it showing no attribute name in set
Please help me to show the list of all player names in house_name: shivalik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the queryset of players. Like this:

**shivalik.html**

```
{% for player in set1 %}
    {{ player.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Just substitute the name attribute for the attribute from the player model you want to iterate over.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers. There already was a similar answer when you posted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for) tag to print name in template.

```
{% for player in set1 %}
    <p>{{player.name}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```